# Haskell IO(a,b)->b

Tags: haskell

In haskell, I have a function defined like this:

```
    f :: IO(CurlCode, String)
```

I want to get the second parameter (the String) from this function, but I cannot figure out how, because I cannot make a function like this:

```
    IO(a,b)->b
```

Comment: You'd have to use `unsafePerformIO` to do that, which as the name implies is unsafe.

Comment: `f` is a value of type `IO (CurlCode, String)`, that is, a tuple (consisting of a `CurlCode` value and a `String` value) embedded in an `IO` action.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1971010 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That's precisely like asking "How can I extract a slice of cake from this cake recipe?" Yes, it's possible to write a hack that looks like it's doing that using GHC and its particular runtime system, but that is *not* part of the Haskell language proper and is *not* a good idea. What you want to do is to build an `IO` action that performs `f` and uses its result:

```
g :: IO String
g = snd <$> f
```

More generally, you can use the result as the other answer describes:

```
foo :: IO ()
foo = f >>= \(code,str) -> putStrLn str
```

which can be written using `do` notation like this:

```
foo = do
  (code, str) <- f
  putStrLn str
```